# Kafka connect - Snapshot Isolation issue - Debezium

Tags: sql-server, debezium, mssql-jdbc

Environment: MS SQL <> Debezium <> Kafka connect

Problem: Random failures for database connector

Current resolution: Have to enable snapshot isolation everytime on database and restart the connector.

Reason: unknown

Detail:
So while using a SQL CDC to Debezium Kafka Connector, we are getting the following error randomly (days apart):

Status is this:

```json
{
  "name": "debezium-sql-connector",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    ...
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "trace": <pasted below formatted>
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

Trace:

```java
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.throwProducerFailureIfPresent(ChangeEventQueue.java:171)
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.poll(ChangeEventQueue.java:151)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorTask.poll(SqlServerConnectorTask.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'sqldb1' because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation.
    at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:179)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:87)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'sqldb1' because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:5427)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1758)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1016)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.lambda$singleResultMapper$7(SqlServerConnection.java:254)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:540)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:408)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.getMaxLsn(SqlServerConnection.java:119)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource.determineSnapshotOffset(SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:154)
    at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:137)
    ... 6 more
```

What could be the basic reason causing it to fail randomly?

If it is because of disabling database snapshot isolation after initialization, that leads to another question. Is it necessary to keep database snapshot isolation enabled all the time? It was done on the initialization time and many other connectors are still working fine.

What can be done to prevent it?

Comment: Reading the error message there's a big ol' "Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'sqldb1' because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation." right in there. I would propose that it's not failing "randomly" but is failing against that specific database. The cause and the solution are in that error message.

Comment: Yes you are right, enabling snapshot isolation for problematic database and then restarting connector fixes the problem each time. But it is random in the sense that any of hundreds of deployed connector will fail. Cause unknown.

Comment: Are you saying that this same database will change its value for whether snapshot isolation is allowed? If so, I'd track down what is changing that. I would look into either DDL triggers or extended events (testing either solution in a non-production environment first).

Comment: A little explanation, snapshot isolation is manually changed back to disabled state by the team every time, stating its nature which might cause problems in write/update operations. Which leads to the 2nd question i asked, Is it necessary to keep database snapshot isolation enabled all the time? It was done on the initialization time and many other connectors are still working fine.

Comment: Okay. The choices you and your team are making are causing your problem. With no pun intended, commit to either turning snapshot isolation on and leaving it there or turn it off and set [snapshot.isolation.mode](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-snapshot-isolation-mode) for the connector to something other than snapshot. As you're discovering, running the connector as configured and having the database not configured to allow for snapshot transactions doesn't work.

Comment: That is true and we are looking in other snapshot isolation modes but as stated in documentation "Mode choice also affects data consistency." So we are studying our options. And, regardless of that, main purpose of raising this was identifying the cause of it, as our possible misinterpretation of documentation was that snapshot lock is used to [perform an initial snapshot](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-snapshots) only.

Comment: I think that the default workflow assumes that you will be using the live database to perform the initial snapshot and as such describes how the snapshot mode changes the locking behavior. Wondering out loud if you can use either an offline copy of the database or a database snapshot with either `initial` or `initial_only` for the snapshot.mode and then transitioning to the CDC data once you've consumed the initial snapshot.

Comment: For offline copy, not sure how we can perform the transition. But for the snapshot.mode, the default value is `initial`, and hence we are relying on it as whenever we did made a connector, the verification was done by comparing N of table rows to kafka topic records. And afterwards, in any point in time, the records in topic will be N+(change events in CDC), meaning shift to CDC is working. And that is what makes it strange, asking for snapshots again.

Comment: I'm not going to guarantee that there's a way to transition, but I'd be shocked if there wasn't one. Imagine a case where you move the live database to another server and you need to change the connection string to the new server. Surely that doesn't require that you re-init, right?